# React Native Production level code and error handling

Tags: android, ios, react-native, error-handling, exception

I know this kind of question has been asked several times. But i didn't find anything that answers my question properly. So here is the question.

I am currently working on react native app. I didn't have any experience with app development before I started working on this app.

So far i got the app to work. It does things as I want. But how do I handle cases where app keeps crashing. For example If the phone is not connected to wifi, app crashes. For once i thought i could add something like

```
if(no internet)
    display "No Internet connection"
else
    display page
```

But this does not look to be efficient in any way. Lets say that the app is connected to internet, page gets displayed, what if the internet gets disconnected while the page is displayed, how do i handle it?

Is this how its done in production level app? if not how should these kind of common errors be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use NetInfo module that is built in in react native [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#netinfo) or use this library [react-native-connection-info](https://github.com/zaromev/react-native-connection-info)

Comment: My question is not just specific to wifi connection error. But in general if i have any other error what is the right way of handling it.